# any math success stories after a failure?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am a sophomore who took abstract algebra for the first time. Started out with Bs, just learned that I failed the course, which is to be expected given the fast decline of my mental health.

However, after getting such a grade, I'm too afraid of even thinking about getting back up. How can I even consider graduate studies in mathematics when I can't even pass such a class. Is it even possible to rise again.

Anyone had a similar story, or some motivating facts from their personal lives to share?

It just seems a reach to even consider grad school after such a failure, and someone sharing stories similar to this one would be of great comfort.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As a student (20 years ago) I would often go through modules thinking I had understood nothing.  However it is amazing how many links your brain makes without you even realising.  If you go through your notes again slowly and patiently, you will remember comments that the lecturer made, that seemed meaningless at the time, but will now appreciate the nuances.  If it is really what you want, you may even get a deep enough understanding to eventually go on to do research (I am still in the game 20 years later).

Comment: I dropped out of my final year of pure mathematics for similar reasons, so I never wrote an undergraduate thesis, and switched to a different computing subject where it was easier for me to finish my final year. After a few years away, I returned to pure maths and have now completed my PhD.

Comment: academia SE is a right place for such question.

Comment: I nearly failed my first algebra class because I took it too lightly. Made me restudy the whole thing in all seriousness, and the material (field extensions, Galois theory) has become one of my favourite areas of mathematics. I still learn new things about it though, one never understands it all!

Comment: Oh and I am very happy I wrote a Ph.D. thesis on a topic which worked out. After two topics which did not. Lucked out there that I got another chance from the powers that be.

Comment: unfortunately my lecturer did not even teach the course. We had to teach it to ourselves which I believe plays some role in my failing

Answer (score 4):

Get back up. This is precisely why mathematics is such an excellent field of study. You are presented with ideas that truly challenge you. Eventually, the light comes on and the sense of accomplishment you get when you finally own an idea you couldn't previously understand is like being high.

I never failed a course but, as an undergraduate, I took a course in Mathematical Logic. We used the book, "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" by Herb Enderton. I was not used to this level of abstraction and I had a better chance of getting through Finnegan's Wake than that book.

A couple years later, I was in graduate school and I took the graduate version of this course. At some point I got stuck on something and I tried to look it up in my copy of Enderton. Not only did the text not cover the material that I was looking for, but it was too basic. This book that seemed so esoteric at one time now read like a high school text.

Mathematics is a discipline. You can spend the rest of your life doing it and you will always be exposed to new ideas. Go for it.